# How can I add data to a specific Firebase child under a key?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add data my set value to a specific database child under a key. Here is my code:

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chat");




    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        textView_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textView_decription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        textView_address =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
        textView_phone =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(phone);
        textView_Pickup =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(pickup);
        textView_Confirm =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(confirm);
        bconfirm = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bcomfirm);
        bpickup = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bpickup);


        bpickup.setOnClickListener(this);
        bconfirm.setOnClickListener(this);



    }
    //new
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == bpickup.getId()) {
            //set action



            reference.child("pickup").setValue("Confirmed time");

        }
    }
```

I feel that it needs to be under my onClick, but I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Simple demo for you.

You have to make a listner for firebase to control.

```
private void firebasedata() {
    String url = "https://xxxx-xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/xxxxx";
    new Firebase(url).addChildEventListener(
            new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    UrlString.add((String) dataSnapshot.child("pickup").getValue());
                    //do everything you want here

                    //for example:
                    // ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(UrlString.get(0), imageView, Picturebit.ImageUsing);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    UrlString.add((String) dataSnapshot.child("pickup").getValue());
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }
            });
}
```

in your case
 try the following

```
reference = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("pickup");
reference.push().setValue(message);
```

take a look here. find a method **updateChildren()**.

[firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write](http://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: I just don't understand how it will then be able to update under a key within the database

Comment: try  Reference.push().setValue(message);

Comment: That adds a new key to the database. I need to be able to overwrite the value of a child already under a key

Comment: take a look here. find a method updateChildren().
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Ok so the key and childs in the database are being generated prior to this from another app what I'm trying to do is essentially a like button or comment button that when clicked changes the textview that's under a specific key .. so essentially I need to retrieve that key then use it to overwrite the existing child (pickup)

Answer (score 0):

If you would want to update a specific record in your database, you need to query its key first. After you get its key, you can update it through:

```
firebaseReference.child("pickup").child("<Record Key").setValue(message)
```

You could also try the **updateChildren()** method but I suggest for you to read this if you plan on using that:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: That's where I'm at is trying to get the specific key then set the value of that child under that key

Comment: Use a Firebase query:

firebaseReference.child("pickup").orderByChild("childName").equalTo("yourCriteria").getKey();